# Listview with spinner in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

Hey guys I am trying to create a menu using a listview with the code I have shown below. The code I have shown will show Item1, Item2 and Item3 in a list. Now I want to be able to add a spinner to item1 and item2. Is that possible? If so how would i go about doing it.

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

String[] MyList = new String[] { "Item1","Item2","Item3"};

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyList));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. Try the following code. You will get it.

```
String[] MyList = new String[] { "Item1","Item2","Item3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create custom list view for doing that you can start by following this particular tutorial :

[Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

This link may be helpful to  you :

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149550/android-spinners-within-a-listview-loose-their-values-when-i-add-dynamically-ne)