# Programatically create and populate spinner and textview with the same style

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-spinner

here my XML code to create the `Spinner` with `TextView` in the `RelativeLayout`. here i need this design pattern dynamically with the exact style.
u can find the style [here](http://i62.tinypic.com/5ysvia.png)      http://i62.tinypic.com/5ysvia.png

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >`

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_ApproveLine"
        style="@style/spinner_style"

        android:paddingLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout_app"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_app"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_label_bg" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Approve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:text="@string/text_approval"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/text_line"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my static XML code . 
i want this exact style dynamically and populate the data dynamically

Thank You !!!

Comment: And what have you try so far?

Comment: everything is fine , i can display spinner with the data from Json , but struggling to present this style ?

Comment: its the static one , i need it to be done by pragmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
android:dropDownSelector=""
```

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/5ysvia.png refer this image , values for the dropdown is from Web service , then how to populate it  . everything needs to be done dynamically

Answer (score 0):

i just modified your code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >`

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_ApproveLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout_app"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout_app"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_app"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/Approve"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:paddingRight="5dp"
             android:paddingTop="7dp"
             android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is the sample one i have statically . i want this to be achieved pragmatically ? any idea ? do i need to inflate with dummy or i have to create new ?

Comment: then create custom list view in listview create two field text n spinner

Comment: its not a list view witty ! its just a spinner , all am worrying is abt the exact format what i have there ? u can click the link and view the image @Meghna

Comment: why u want it programmatically.also i m not saying to change your spinner.

Comment: in my case , the number of spinner is varying for diff users . the data for the  spinner items too !!! spinner item and the label for the spinner to be populated with the Dynamic JSON content ... find the spinner image here @Meghna [link]([IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/10er1x4.png[/IMG])[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/10er1x4.png[/IMG]

Comment: [IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/10er1x4.png[/IMG] its like a form , which contains several spinner already , i need to create a new spinner dynamically with the existing style ... u can find the style in the image link @Meghna this the sample style .

Comment: you want to create spinner dynamically??As u said u r getting spinner n data.can you tell exactly wht type of style u are getting??

Comment: Yes , dynamically . i am getting label , and spinner one by one, and not the same design which i mention in the image link

Comment: dept. A/c,dept.Admin these are spinner..all are containing some value.if it s,i have already said u create Custom Listview with Text and Spinner,not simple Listview i am saying.Mark it.check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952375/android-listview-with-spinner-and-a-checkbox.it may help ur requirement